# Can't load images from nested vue components

Tags: image, vue.js

I have created a project using PHPStorm so all of the files and folders were generated.

So, I have a few nested components and for some weird reason just don't load on the page. I have tried a variety of:

`assets`
`/assets`
`../assets`
`/../assets`
`../../assets`
... and so on.

Here is the folder structure:

[image: Folder Structure]

Slider.vue is inside Home.vue and here is the code for the slider:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-bind:key="data.id"  class="carousel container" v-for="data in todos" v-html="data.content"></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data: function() {
            return {
                todos:
                    [
                        {
                            id: 1,
                            content: `
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <h3>Overview</h3>
                            </div>
                            <img class="lozad mob" alt="Dashboard Overview" src="/assets/browser_overview--mobile.png" data-loaded="true">
                            <img class="lozad mid" alt="Dashboard Overview" data-src="../../assets/browser_overview--mid.png" src="../../assets/browser_overview--mid.png" data-loaded="true">
                            <img class="lozad large" alt="Dashboard Overview" data-src="../../assets/browser_overview--large.png" src="../../assets/browser_overview--large.png" data-loaded="true">
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <p>
                                Text
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    `
                        }
                    ],
                interval: null,
                soonTodo: [
                    {
                        id: 2,
                        content: `
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <h3>Popup</h3>
                            </div>
                            <img class="lozad mob" alt="Dashboard Popup" data-src="../assets/browser_popup--mobile.png" src="../assets/browser_popup--mobile.png" data-loaded="true">
                            <img class="lozad mid" alt="Dashboard Popup" data-src="../assets/browser_popup--mid.png" src="../assets/browser_popup--mid.png" data-loaded="true">
                            <img class="lozad large" alt="Dashboard Popup" data-src="../assets/browser_popup--large.png" src="../assets/browser_popup--large.png" data-loaded="true">
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <p>
                                Text
                            </p>
                        </div>

                    `,
                    },
                ]
            }
        },
        created() {
            let i = 0;
            this.interval = setInterval(() => {
                this.todos = [];
                if (this.soonTodo.length) {
                    this.todos.push(this.soonTodo[i]);
                    ++i;
                    if (i == this.soonTodo.length) {
                        i = 0;
                    }
                } else {
                    clearInterval(this.interval);
                }
            }, 9000)
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're putting all your content as HTML strings instead of using Vue template. Hence, Vue is not compiling it and transforming your `src` paths like it normally would. In this case, you could move all the images from `/src/assets` to `/public` folder. I'd prefer having a `/public/images` folder and placing them there.

Now, you can change your `src` into `/images/your_image.jpg` to get this to work. (Note: plain `src`, not `:src`).

Side note: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-public-folder in case if you're deploying under a domain's path and not root (`/`).

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to replace `src` to `:src`?

Upd.

You can try to add to webpack this config:

```
const path = require('path');

...

resolve: {
    alias: {
        '@': path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
    }
},
```

And then you can use this path:

```
<img :src="@/assets/browser_overview--mid.png">
```

@ - should be referenced to your root project directory.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't make a difference either

Comment: Are you sure that images is accessible? Does it have appropriate permissions?